# GSON password serialization policy

Tags: java, serialization, gson

I want to create serialization policy, that would decode fields in objects which are passwords. If the field's name contains 'password' I would like GSON to use my defined encryption alghoritm. I tried to extend TypeAdapter and plug it to GsonBuilder, but then I loose all functionality from TreeTypeAdapter. Any ideas?

I have something like this but I need to do all the work from TreeTypeAdapter myself:

```
public class PasswordStringAdapter extends TypeAdapter<String> {


    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, String value) throws IOException {

        String keyName = getKeyName(out);

    }

    private String getKeyName(JsonWriter writer) {

        try {
            Field name = writer.getClass().getDeclaredField("deferredName");
            name.setAccessible(true);
            String fieldName = (String) name.get(writer);

            //if field name contains password then encode it

        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It tured out that after decoding my password I just need to do:

```
out.value(value);
```

Please comment if you have better ideas how to do that.